# Z-index in front of an element in a fixed position

Tags: css, z-index, fixed, absolute

I do not find a solution to my problem so I turn to you :).

Here is the context: I have two brothers elements, one is absolute position and the other is in a fixed position. Basic the fixed element is always at the top. Consider in the code below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#element1 {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#element2 {
  background: green;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
}
#element3 {
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#element1,
#element3 {
  z-index: 1;
} 
#element2 {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div id="element1">
  <div>
     <div id="element2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="element3">

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P7c9q/1162/

That the green color area is a modal. My objective is to make the element green over the element in a fixed position.

How can I unlock myself knowing that element 1 and element 2 must remain in absolute position?

Thank you in advance,
cordially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element3` will always be over `element1` and all its children even if a child of `element1` has higher `z-index` because its finally related to its parent `element1` which has lower `z-index` than `element3`

There are two solutions to this case:

1. put `element2` and `element3` as children for `element1`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#element1 {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#element2 {
  background: green;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
}
#element3 {
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#element1,
#element3 {
  z-index: 1;
} 
#element2 {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div id="element1">
  <div>
     <div id="element2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="element3">

  </div>
</div>
```

2. make `element2` outside `element1` in the same level with `element3`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#element1 {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#element2 {
  background: green;
  top:25%;
  left:15%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 600px;
}
#element3 {
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="element1"></div>
<div id="element2"></div>
<div id="element3"></div>
```

Comment: I will send element three in element two, it is more appropriate to my problem, a big thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#element1 {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#element2 {
  background: green;
  top:25%;
  left:15%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 600px;
}
#element3 {
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="element1">
  <div>
     <div id="element2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="element3">

</div>
```

Comment: This is also a solution but I can't change the position of element two in fixed. Thank you for your help.